# Filter in excel sheet using a formula with respect to multiple criterias

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, filtering, input-filtering

I have a problem with my excel spreadsheet. I have hourly timeseries data of a variable (lets call it X) for different geographical areas, and the coherent temperature for each point in time. I would like to create a simple sheet filtering for multiple different criteria - these are:

- Geographical Area (4 different areas in the dataset. The area represents where the X variable and the temperature is measured)
- Year
- Week number
- Week day
- Hour
- Temperature

I would like to be able to have multiple selection of Area, Year, Weeknumber, Weekday, Hour and to be able to select a temperature range.

For instance, selecting:

Area: 2 (out of 4)

Year: 2019, 2020

Week number: 2,3,4

Week day: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday

Hour: 5 pm, 6pm, 7pm

Temperature range: -5 degrees to +5 degrees

Ideally, my output would then be an array of my X variable filtered on these selections.

Currently my formula looks like this:

=FILTER('BackEnd (Area)'!B5:K36484;(('BackEnd (Area)'!J5:J36484<T5)*('BackEnd (Area)'!J5:J36484>U5))*
ISNUMBER(MATCH('BackEnd (Area)'!B5:B36484;'BackEnd (Time period)'!M3:M54;0))*
ISNUMBER(MATCH('BackEnd (Area)'!D5:D36484;'BackEnd (Time period)'!K3:K54;0))*
ISNUMBER(MATCH('BackEnd (Area)'!C5:C36484;'BackEnd (Time period)'!L3:L54))*ISNUMBER(MATCH('BackEnd (Area)'!F5:F36484;'BackEnd (Time period)'!J3:J54));1)

However, the filter formula does not take all of my selections into account. Please, can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have a sample data set with expected output so we can replicate the issue and work towards an answer?

Comment: You're not consistent in using `*` and/or `+` between your different conditions. We can't judge what it should be without sample data

Comment: Would be good to see a sample of the data (e.g. in table within Q) - some type of illustration of expected v actual output, something to work from so that those attempting to assist you don't have to recreate everything from a wordy description...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without recreating the data, try this:

```
=FILTER('BackEnd (Area)'!B5:K36484;(('BackEnd (Area)'!J5:J36484<T5)*('BackEnd (Area)'!J5:J36484>U5))*ISNUMBER(MATCH('BackEnd (Area)'!B5:B36484;'BackEnd (Time period)'!M3:M54;0))* ISNUMBER(MATCH('BackEnd (Area)'!D5:D36484;'BackEnd (Time period)'!K3:K54;0))* ISNUMBER(MATCH('BackEnd (Area)'!C5:C36484;'BackEnd (Time period)'!L3:L54))*ISNUMBER(MATCH('BackEnd (Area)'!F5:F36484;'BackEnd (Time period)'!J3:J54));1)
```